# mvc4 passing data between paging action and views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have an action which will invoke a service (not database)to get some data for display,and i want to do paging on these data.however,every time a second page is clicked,it will invoke this action and of course invoke the service again,actually when i click the first page link,it already generate the whole data including what the second page needs. i just want to invoke the service once and get all the data,and later when paging,i don't need to invoke the service again,how can i deal with that?hope someone could give me a hint~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to address this. If it's practical and a limited amount of data, it's ok to return the entire data set in the first request. 
If that's your case I would consider returning a pure JSON object when you load the page initially. You can then deserialize this into a JS object variable on the web page that you can perform your paging operations against. This is an example of client side paging where all the data exists client side.

Another approach is to do Ajax based paging where you request the data for the next page as needed. I would still recommend returning JSON in this scenario as well.

The two approaches differ in that the first one returns all the data upfront, whereas the second one only returns what you need to render any given page.

Comment: i'd like every page to have a unique url(actually a url with page parameter ),so i think the first approach(using button and js)might not work.About the second approach,because the service can only get the whole data (in fact,the service is like a full text search ),so even if i use ajax,every time i call ajax,it will still return the whole data.

Comment: I guess one way to limit the performance hot of running the query every time is to cache the result of the search on the server. That way you can do the paging in memory based on url paging parameters